# Injectivity is a local property

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, injective-module

Let $R$  be a commutative noetherian ring, and let $M$  be an $R$-module. How can I show that if any localization $M_p$  at a prime ideal $p$  of the ring $R$  is injective over $R_p$, then $M$  is injective?

Comment: The same question was asked on mathoverflow one or two days ago, but it seems to be deleted. Someone had also posted the proof there.

Answer (score 3):

Baer's criterion shows that it suffices to show that $\hom(B,M) \to \hom(A,M)$ is surjective for $B=R$ and $A=$ an ideal, in particular both are finitely presented. But then $\hom$ commutes with localization and we are done.

Comment: You're implicitly using the Noetherianness here, Martin.  In general, I think Hom only commutes with localization when the first variable is finitely presented.

Comment: That's exactly what I am saying. A ring is noetherian iff all ideals are finitely presented, and this is what I use. Your last sentence coincides with the last sentence in my answer.

Comment: thank you for the answer but I already know this proof and Im looking for a proof that is NOT using finitely presented property.In fact I want this for some  people who dont know any thing about finitely presented.

Comment: @Martin: Right; good point.  Didn't mean to offend.  I just thought I should make the point for readers who might not know this subtlety (as this is part of the point of math.SE -- explaining what's going on under the hood)